# reg expression to truncate a string from last dot

Tags: regex

I have following string and I want to strip the last part starting from dot. Could you please advise? I am new to reg expressions.
[abc].[def]**.[ghi]**

Thanks,
mc

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Hints: `[^.]` matches anychar but a dot, and `$` matches the end of the input `;)`

Comment: dont give a job to regex when you language can do it. Which language are you using ?

Comment: This is a useful tool to learn regex: [regexr](http://regexr.com)

Comment: Agreed with @Bob0t - for instance a JS solution might be `input.split(".").slice(0,-1).join(".")`

Comment: Sorry guys for not puting any effort from myside. I am trying to do this in a BI tool(Cognos)

Comment: So, regex only? Look at what sp00m wrote in the first comment. Use `[.][^.]*$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `regexp` you need is:

```
(.*?)(?:\.[^.]*)?$
```

**The `regexp` piece by piece:**

```
(          # start of the first capturing sub-pattern
  .*       # matches any character, any number of times (zero or more)
  ?        # make the previous quantifier (`*`) not greedy
)          # end of the first sub-pattern
(?:        # start of the second sub-pattern; it doesn't capture the matching string
  \.       # matches a dot (.)
  [^.]*    # matches anything but a dot (.), any number of times (zero or more)
)          # end of the second sub-pattern
?          # the previous sub-expression (the non-capturing sub-pattern) is optional
$          # matches the end of the string
```

**How it works:**

The first part `(.*?)` matches and captures everything until the last dot. The question mark (`?`) makes the zero or more quantifier (`*`) not greedy. It is greedy by default and, because of the second sub-expression have to be optional (read below), its greediness makes it match the entire string.

The `?:` specifier at the start of the second sub-pattern makes it non-capturing. The sub-string it matches is not stored and it's not available for further use.

The second sub-pattern contains `\.[^.]*` and matches a dot (`.`) followed by zero or more characters but none of them can be dots. It doesn't match anything if the input string doesn't contain a dot and this makes the entire `regexp` not matching. This is why it is marked as optional by following it with a question mark (`?`).

Most tools that work with `regexp` provide a way to get and use the captured strings using `$n` or `\n` as placeholders in the replacement string. `n` above is the number of the capturing pattern, counting by its open parenthesis `(`. Since we have only one capturing sub-pattern, the substring it matches should be available either as `$1` or `\1` (or both, or using a different syntax).

You can play with this `regexp` on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/aS7iQ7/1).